# Difference in HTML checkbox 'checked' property/attribute in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

See JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gK6kX/11/ has the lines:

```
$("input#aaa")[0].checked = false;
$("input#aaa")[0].setAttribute('checked', false);
```

The third box is checked on Chrome but not IE (IE9).

I understand why it's checked on Chrome - checked="false" means the box is still checked.

I *don't* understand why it *isn't* checked on IE.

It looks as if the first line (`checked = false` on the DOM object, vs. setAttribute) somehow makes a difference on IE, but not Chrome.

What does this first line do?  And why would someone have used both lines rather than just `setAttribute`?

Comment: I believe you may have ran into a bug here. JQuery 1.10.1 on JSFiddle doesn't seem to be working in IE. Can you confirm the code is actually executing by putting an alert after it? If not, try another jQuery version. It should behave the same in IE, as you noticed the static version does do so.

Comment: That may have been it. With a different jQuery version, I got the same results in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Updated question - really the issue is about the checked attribute vs. the checked property

Comment: Better formulation of the question I was trying to ask:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994135/precedence-when-html-form-element-attributes-and-properties-conflict

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, use `$.attr()` to set the initial checked state. Use `$.prop()` to change the property after the fact. So, if you have a checkbox that is loaded and already checked, do this to uncheck it:

```
$("input#aaa")[0].prop('checked', true); // set checked
$("input#aaa")[0].prop('checked', false); // uncheck
```

Note that if the `checked` attribute is present on the element at all, regardless of its value, then the initial state of the checkbox should be considered checked. This is [according to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4). So, if you have `checked="false"` on the checkbox, *it'll still be checked*. The `checked` attribute only sets the initial state of the checkbox via the `defaultChecked` property. To change the state of the checkbox thereafter, you need to modify the `checked` property (the attribute no longer matters).

Doing this is technically for setting the initial state of the checkbox:

```
$("input#aaa")[0].attr('checked', 'checked'); // initial state is checked
```

Again, if you want to change the checked state after the checkbox has been created, use `$.prop()`.

Reference (I suggest reading both pages in their entirety):

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: doesn't answer my question - asking about specific discrepancy between browsers for given code

Comment: @wrschneider99 `setAttribute` is for setting the attribute `checked` and therefore the property `defaultChecked` - this property is for the initial state of the checkbox. If you want to modify the state after that, you should be changing the property `checked`, not the attribute.

Comment: @wrschneider99 Ok, now I see your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what's wrong. But, if you change to jQuery 1.9, things work as you'd expect. I'm actually having issues with 1.10 in all versions of IE. http://jsfiddle.net/gK6kX/9/