# Precedence when HTML form element attributes and properties conflict

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I notice a discrepancy in behavior between browsers and different types of form elements, when form element DOM attributes are set in conflict with current state from the same element's properties.

See
http://jsfiddle.net/Ldf2s/7/

```
document.forms['foo'].bar.checked=false;
document.forms['foo'].bar.setAttribute("checked", "true");

document.forms['foo'].baz.value = 'prop value';
document.forms['foo'].baz.setAttribute("value", "attr value");
```

*In IE 9*: property wins for both text input and checkbox (shows "prop value" and unchecked)

*In Chrome*: property wins over attribute for text input ("prop value" shown) BUT checkbox is checked.

Why the difference between text input and checkboxes, and why the difference only for Chrome?

And what is the precedence supposed to be?  If you change the DOM attributes, should that or should that not overwrite the current form input state?

Comment: "checked" is behaves like a property, not an attribute. You need to use .setAttribute("checked", "checked"), not true/false.

Comment: The value for the 'checked' attribute doesn't matter - only its presence or absence.  The question is about foo.checked vs. foo.setAttribute("checked").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take at look at http://jsfiddle.net/Ldf2s/9/.

```
<form name="foo">
    <input name="bar" type="checkbox" />
    <input name="baz" type="text"/>
</form>

<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms['foo'].bar.setAttribute("checked", "true");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms['foo'].baz.setAttribute("value", "attr value");
}, 5000);
</script>
```

If you run the page and don't touch the input boxes, after 5 seconds the checkbox will be ticked and value will be set. But if you run the page and immediately click on the checkbox and type some text in the text input, the values will not be modified once 5 seconds has elapsed.

The concepts to be understood here are the **dirty checkedness flag** and the **dirty value flag**.

What these do is to mark the checkbox and text input fields as to whether `document.forms['foo'].bar.setAttribute("checked", "true");` and `document.forms['foo'].baz.setAttribute("value", "attr value");` affect the checkedness and value of the respective inputs or not.

For the dirty checkedness flag, [the HTML5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-checked-dirty)

> Each input element has a checkedness, which is exposed by the checked IDL attribute.
>
> Each input element has a boolean dirty checkedness flag. When it is true, the element is said to have a dirty checkedness. The dirty checkedness flag must be initially set to false when the element is created, and must be set to true whenever the user interacts with the control in a way that changes the checkedness.
>
> The checked content attribute is a boolean attribute that gives the default checkedness of the input element. When the checked content attribute is added, if the control does not have dirty checkedness, the user agent must set the checkedness of the element to true; when the checked content attribute is removed, if the control does not have dirty checkedness, the user agent must set the checkedness of the element to false.

So in the JSFiddle above the act of the user clicking the checkbox stops the `setAttribute` call affecting whether the checkbox is checked or not.

However, it also says that

> The checked IDL attribute allows scripts to manipulate the checkedness of an input element. On getting, it must return the current checkedness of the element; and **on setting, it must** set the element's checkedness to the new value and **set the element's dirty checkedness flag to true**.

So `document.forms['foo'].bar.checked=false;` should also have the effect of stopping the `setAttribute` call from setting the checked state because it too should make the dirty checkedness flag true.

But in Chrome the checked value is changed, so it is inconsistent with the HTML5 spec.

---

The HTML5 spec also has an analogous requirement for the text input value in that there is a dirty value flag that is set true when the user changes the value, or the value property is set programatically.

It seems in this case Chrome behaves correctly, possibly because the requirement to set the dirty value flag when the value property is set programatically is made explicitly when describing the dirty value flag, whereas the equivalent description of the dirty checkedness flag does not have the matching comment. That requirement is only given separately in the quote above.

Comment: The discrepancy must be that Chrome doesn't consider the checked=false statement as making the checkbox dirty, because the checkbox did not change from its initial state.  (Perhaps optimizing out a no-op?)  IE must have unconditionally treated the assignment as setting the dirty checkedness flag.  
 
See this modification: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldf2s/11/ - if  the checkbox is initially checked, then a call to checked=false will prevent a subsequent setAttribute("checked") call from checking the box.

Comment: not sure if this is actually a bug in Chrome - depends on how you define "setting".

Answer (score 1):

Browsers differ, partly because there have been no exact, consensus-based definitions for the DOM features involved. In HTML5, this is being standardized: the [`input` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) is defined to that the `checked` property (“IDL attribute”, as they call it) describes the actual checkedness state (which as affected by user actions and by JavaScript code), whereas the `defaultChecked` property corresponds to the HTML attribute `checked`, which sets the *initial* checkedness.

In the example code in the question, the `checked` property is set to the value `false`, which does not change anything (it is the initial value, in the absence of the `checked` attribute). Then the `checked` attribute, and thereby the `defaultChecked` property, is set, but this does not change the checkedness state.

Thus, Chrome does not work by the HTML5 draft. This is formally just a feature, since there is so far no approved specification, but in practical terms, it can be described as a bug.

For a text input box, `input type=text`, there is no such issue, since the `value` property more directly reflects the `value` attribute (there is no separate `defaultValue` property).

Comment: There most definitely is a [defaultValue property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-defaultvalue):